# NPAPI BasicPlugin in C++

Tags: plugins, npapi

This basic [npapi plugin](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/mac-basic) is written in C. I'm developing on Mac and using xcode the project compiles and works. But I would like it to be in C++, what should I do to convert this to a C++ project? Or is there a similar example available in C++?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And as I usually do, I will recommend that you look at FireBreath (http://www.firebreath.org) if you haven't already.  It's an abstraction that will solve a lot of the grief of writing NPAPI plugins for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rename BasicPlugin.c to BasicPlugin.cc (or .cpp, or whatever C++ suffix you like). .Do this from the Xcode UI, so the project will be updated automatically.

There is no step 2. Once the file is being treated as a C++ file by the compiler, you can add all all the C++ you want. C++ is a superset of C, so all the existing code should work as-is.